# How to use strip_shortcodes() from a spawned process?

Tags: shortcode

I have a plug-in that spawns a process to carry out a print function. The item to print, in this case a Woocommerce product, is passed via the URL (via `product_id`). Before carrying out printing, all registered shortcodes must be stripped from the product description. If I call `strip_shortcodes()` it does nothing. I guess the array of registered shortcodes is out of scope? Can anyone suggest an efficient way to enable the process to use `strip_shortcodes()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add shortcodes to the array of tags to be stripped in [`strip_shortcodes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/) via filter. If the global `$shortcode_tags` either doesn't exist or doesn't contain what it should when your process is running then you'll need to use that filter to add them back in.

```
$tags_to_remove = apply_filters( 'strip_shortcodes_tagnames', $tags_to_remove, $content );
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to bring `$shortcode_tags` into scope before calling `strip_shortcodes()`

I did this by adding the declaration

```
global $shortcode_tags;
```